# LTI system Bode curve

Tags: control-system, bode-plot, linear

Given an RLC circuit, I needed to find the transfer function, which I did. Now I need to find R and L so that the next two conditions are met:

1. The overshoot is 25%
2. The first peak time is t = 3

The capacitor is C = 1.
Any guidance on how can I find R and L?

I tried to use the peak time and the overshoot equation, but I got stuck with a complex algebra and I got R = minus something which doesn't make sense.

here is what i did

[image]

then I got stuck with the algebra..

Comment: Are you trying to derive it mathematically @math king <-- why not show the overshoot equation you used and explain whether it was a low-pass filter or not?

Comment: There are four possible transfer functions. Which one did you find.

Comment: I'm sry didn't mention the input is Vin(t) and the output is Vc(t) the transfer function that I came upw with is

 (1\Lc)\(s²+ R/L * s + 1\Lc) and c is 1 so (1\L)\(s²+(R/L)*s+(1\L))

Comment: You need to _edit your question_ with more information.  Show us a schematic of the RLC circuit, and then, since this is clearly homework, show us what you actually tried.

Comment: @TimWescott thanks, i just edited my post with the equations I came up with. it took me time to convert my handwriting to Latex, sry bout that :(